# Can you tell me if my database model is correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a project and I have to create a database for a College to manage grades and permissions to edit them. I have tried to centralize the tables of students and teachers in a single user table, but I do not know if it is correct, someone can advise me or tell me how I can improve or correct the errors, I do not know much about database.

[image]

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It has no errors, I just don't know if it is ok to centralize the students and teachers in a user table or I would need to create individual tables, so that it doesn't generate an error in the future.

Comment: There's no way I can tell right now because I don't have the assignment in front of me. There's no "right way" to do it. You just have to go with something and then if it gives you problems down the road you have to change it. I suggest reading the assignment thoroughly and coming up with a plan before you start coding anything

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you try to avoid duplication. It is not possible to comment without understanding your full requirements, but there shouldn't be a need to create different tables to store similar attributes. have a separate column to identify a student from a teacher.